# R, SQL query in for loop

Tags: mysql, sql, r, for-loop

I have a list that contains customers and their ID. It looks like the one below:

```
customers_id <- list(x = John(1,2,3), Rick = c(4), Sam = c(5,6))
```

and a database that looks like the one below and calls 'db'

```
date        id   value
2017-05-12  1      51 
2017-05-13  2      3  
2017-05-14  3      217
2017-05-15  1      12
2017-05-16  2      98
2017-05-17  3      123
2017-05-18  1      78
2017-05-19  2      36
2017-05-20  4      178
2017-05-18  5      728
2017-05-19  6      336
2017-05-20  4      718
2017-05-18  5      758
2017-05-19  6      366
2017-05-20  4      787
```

I tried to make a for loop but couldn't figuer out the right solution. I think that in the loop should be a query that
will take a correct ID and sum values for ID

```
corect_values <- paste(" SELECT date, id, SUM(value) FROM db WHERE id = '", id, "' ")
```

So I have two issues: How to put a query into for loop and how to write a sql query that will take into account all id for customer.

Result should like the one below:

```
John  618
Rick  1683
Sam   2188
```

Do you have any idea how it can be solved ? 
Thanks for any help !

Comment: add "group by id", this will group by the id. (or you can select with customer table)

Comment: so basically multiple ids have the same user bound to them(eg John is bound to id 1,2,3)?
and if so, why? make one ID for one name.
I could show you in the answer a query that will sum for each of the ID if you want me to

Comment: I think you don't need a loop here. Instead of looping over each id by its own you could select all ids at once using "...WHERE id IN (", id, ")....". you might have to wrap each single id-number in vector id inside ' ' to make this work.

Comment: You could select id and value from db then in R join the names by id and do a sum grouped by name? Or are you specifically trying to do this with a query?

Comment: the issue is that I have over 100 customers and they have from 1 to even 200 ID so I am not sure how I could one ID for one name @AndreiFiordean

Comment: unfortunately I need to use a query

Comment: Yeah sounds like your best option is just querying the entire table and doing the rest of the work in R (by the way there is a typo in your customers_id list). Can you provide a better example of what the customers and id's look like? I will write up an answer in a second.

Comment: But you simply can't group by name if it doesn't exist in your database. Edit: Ok I think I can see how it might be possible but a better example of your customer ids and names would help a lot. I still think it would be just as fast to do all the leg work in r?

Comment: "Yeah sounds like your best option is just querying the entire table and doing the rest of the work in R" and I see that it will be the only good option, although the db is huge. Thanks for help @AndreiFiordean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a data.frame of customer names and id's like so...

```
customers_id <- data.frame(Names = c("John", "John", "John", "Rick", "Sam", "Sam"),
                           id = c(1:6))
```

Query all id and value from db... lets say this is now assigned to df

```
SELECT id, value FROM db
```

Now you can left_join on your names, group by this and sum the value.

```
library(dplyr)

df <- left_join (df, customers_id, by = "id")

result <- df %>% 
  group_by(Names) %>% 
  summarise(value = sum(value))
```

Comment: I tried to use your solution but I got this error
"Error in UseMethod("group_by_") : 
  no applicable method for 'group_by_' applied to an object of class "function""

Answer (score 0):

This code for summation

SELECT SUM(values) total
FROM db
WHERE customers_id = id;

Answer (score 0):

I will try to describe as best as i can:
when you have 2 tables for example:(lets take your tables)

Table_A) `ID, user_name`

Table_B) `ID, date, user_id(matched to the table above as a foreign key), value`

you can do a query like this:

```
SELECT Table_A.user_name, sum(Table_B.value)
FROM Table_A join Table_B on Table_a.ID = Table_B.user_id
GROUP BY Table_A.ID
```

This query will sum all values for all users that you have.
It will only show one entry for each of the user with all of the values summed up

Comment: From my understanding of his question, it sounds like Table A doesn't exist in his db?

Comment: i think so, it might be possible that table A does not exist in his DB and that is why his job is much harder

Comment: You are right, it doesnt exitst as a db. The type is the list

Comment: your life would be much easier if you would just make another table and link it to your target table, that is my advice for you sir

Comment: Can you please fix your example of the id list then? or even `dput()` your customer id list?

Comment: i don't understand what you mean? and are you reffering to me?

Comment: no sorry referring to @Tmiskiewicz. The first line of their question has a typo.

Answer (score 0):

Does this select deliver the desired results?

```
customer_id = sample(c(1:6), 10, replace = T) # just some dummy-user ids as an example

customer_id = paste0("'", customer_id, "'")
customer_id = paste(customer_id, collapse =  ", ")

corect_values = paste0("SELECT sum(value) FROM db where id IN (", customer_id, ") GROUP BY id")
```

ofc it doesn't since you do not want to group by id but by name and name does cover more than just one id.

maybe this can solve the problem.
The drawback is: You still have to make a request for every name. 
So even if the following code works, i think it would still be better to create a reference table in your db to join name and id as @Andrei Fiordean has suggested in the comments.

```
select_this <- function(temp_ids)
{

  temp_ids = paste0("'", temp_ids, "'")
  temp_ids = paste(temp_ids, collapse =  ", ")
  corect_values = paste0("SELECT sum(value) FROM db where id IN (", temp_ids, ")")
  # results = request select from db here
  return(results)
}

customers_id <- list("John" = c(1,2,3), "Rick" = c(4), "Sam" = c(5,6))
sapply(customers_id, select_this)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to use for loop to only run the query for the specific customers then you can do:

```
for (i in 1:length(customers_id)) {

  sql_q <- paste0("SELECT '", names(customers_id)[i], "' AS customer, sum(value) AS value FROM db WHERE id IN (", paste(customers_id[[i]], collapse = ", "), ")")

}
```

`sql_q` returns

```
[1] "SELECT 'John' AS customer, sum(value) AS value FROM db WHERE id IN (1, 2, 3)"
[1] "SELECT 'Rick' AS customer, sum(value) AS value FROM db WHERE id IN (4)"
[1] "SELECT 'Sam' AS customer, sum(value) AS value FROM db WHERE id IN (5, 6)"
```

Then just append the data to get your result, e.g.

```
# Example Data given
customers_id <- list(John = c(1,2,3), Rick = c(4), Sam = c(5,6))

# Assuming you have your db connection setup in 'con'
sql_list <- list()
for (i in 1:length(customers_id)) {

  sql_q <- paste0("SELECT '", names(customers_id)[i], "' AS customer, sum(value) AS value FROM db WHERE id IN (", paste(customers_id[[i]], collapse = ", "), ")")
  sql_d <- sqlQuery(con, sql_q)
  sql_list[[i]] <- sql_d

}

combined_d <- do.call("rbind", sql_list)
```